# Select first and last rows between two dates MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, date

I have query:

```
SELECT id, coins_id, first_coin, second_coin, price, `time`
FROM hist_all
WHERE `time` between (NOW() - interval 120 minute) AND NOW()
  AND (second_coin = 'USD' OR second_coin = 'USDT')
  AND first_coin = 'LSK';
```

Query return:

[image]

> How I can get first and last rows relative to the date ? (In this example first record  is `id=1832`, last `id=14117`)

Comment: This is MySQL? Always tag the rdbms?

Comment: What does it mean the first and last row, when you don't have an `ORDER BY` (the ordering is undefined)

Comment: @EvanCarroll Yes, that's MySQL. I get the value from the last 120 minutes and I need to change my query so that it will only get the latest and oldest record from those 120 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all due time there will be Common Table Expressions (CTE) in MySQL:

```
WITH T AS (
   SELECT id, coins_id, first_coin, second_coin, price, `time`
   FROM hist_all
   WHERE `time` between (NOW() - interval 120 minute) AND NOW()
     AND (second_coin = 'USD' OR second_coin = 'USDT')
     AND first_coin = 'LSK'
) 
(SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY time LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1);
```

If your version of MySQL dont support CTE's you can repeat the query:

```
  (SELECT id, coins_id, first_coin, second_coin, price, `time`
   FROM hist_all
   WHERE `time` between (NOW() - interval 120 minute) AND NOW()
     AND (second_coin = 'USD' OR second_coin = 'USDT')
     AND first_coin = 'LSK'
   ORDER BY TIME LIMIT 1)
   UNION ALL
  (SELECT id, coins_id, first_coin, second_coin, price, `time`
   FROM hist_all
   WHERE `time` between (NOW() - interval 120 minute) AND NOW()
     AND (second_coin = 'USD' OR second_coin = 'USDT')
     AND first_coin = 'LSK'
   ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, In your query with `UNION ALL` i needed add brackets, before `UNION ALL` and after `UNION ALL` ;)

Comment: Ah yes, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

## Using CTEs with MySQL 8

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT id, coins_id, first_coin, second_coin, price, `time`
  FROM hist_all
  WHERE `time` between (NOW() - interval 120 minute) AND NOW()
    AND (second_coin = 'USD' OR second_coin = 'USDT')
    AND first_coin = 'LSK'
) AS t
WITH max_min AS t2 (
  SELECT max(time) AS max,min(time) AS min FROM t1
)
SELECT max_min.*, tmax.*, tmin.*
FROM max_min
INNER JOIN t1 AS tmax ON t1.time = max_min.max
INNER JOIN t1 AS tmin ON t1.time = max_min.min;
```

## Using Window Functions with MySQL 8

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT time = min(time) OVER () OR time = max(time) OVER () AS sel,
    id, coins_id, first_coin, second_coin, price, `time`
  FROM hist_all
  WHERE `time` between (NOW() - interval 120 minute) AND NOW()
    AND (second_coin = 'USD' OR second_coin = 'USDT')
    AND first_coin = 'LSK'
) AS t
WHERE t.sel;
```

## No MySQL 8?

Get [PostgreSQL Today](https://www.postgresql.org/download/), it's freer, not owned by Oracle and better.